# IF condition with ISBLANK using Google Sheets *driving me insane*

Tags: formulas, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet for investment tracking setup and I'm trying to add a ISBLANK to the following formula:

=IF(G67=TRUE,G12, G12*GOOGLEFINANCE(("CURRENCY:USDEUR")))   <--This formula currently works

G67 is basically check if what currency is listed. If EURO, then no conversion, else it convert to EURO.

**Now I want to add an additional check where if there is NO ticker symbol in cell G3 this cell should remain blank. If the ticker symbol is there, then it should do exactly what my current formula does.**

Any ideas how to alter the formula so it add this condition? I'm not very good with complexer formulas and not finding the solution is driving me crazy. : (

Comment: I think Ticker symbol (Insert --> Checkbox) resolves to TRUE or FALSE in Google Sheets. So you can simply wrap your formula in an outer IF checking for TRUE (ticked) or FALSE (Unticked).

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are multiple conditions that should each lead to another type of result, you may want to try with the [ifs()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145) function, like this:

```
=ifs( 
  isblank(G3), iferror(1/0), 
  G67, G12, 
  true, G12 * googlefinance("CURRENCY:USDEUR") 
)
```